# (Scripting) Photoshop removes special characters

Tags: javascript, batch-processing, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a script (with a lot of stolen parts you may recognise) that runs through a selected group of images, copies the image and filename and applies to a template in Photoshop. Everything works just fine, except that Photoshop somehow strips umlauts from my strings, ie, Björn becomes Bjorn.

"Logging" through an alert inside of Photoshop (line #30 below) shows that it has the correct string all the way until it's applied as the textItem.contents.

Code provided below, thanks for any help!

```js
#target photoshop
app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;

var templateRef = app.activeDocument;
var templatePath = templateRef.path;
var photo = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("Photo"); // keycard_template.psd is the active document


// Check if photo layer is SmartObject;
if (photo.kind != "LayerKind.SMARTOBJECT") {
    alert("selected layer is not a smart object")
} else {
    // Select Files;
    if ($.os.search(/windows/i) != -1) {
        var photos = File.openDialog("Select photos", "*.png;*.jpg", true)
    } else {
        var photos = File.openDialog("Select photos", getPhotos, true)
    };
    if (photos.length) replaceItems();
}

function replaceItems() {
    for (var m = 0; m < photos.length; m++) {
        if (photos.length > 0) {
            // Extract name
            var nameStr = photos[m].name;
            var nameNoExt = nameStr.split(".");
            var name = nameNoExt[0].replace(/\_/g, " ");

            // Replace photo and text in template
            photo = replacePhoto(photos[m], photo);
            // alert(name);
            replaceText(templateRef, 'Name', name);        

            templateRef.saveAs((new File(templatePath + "/keycards/" + name + ".jpg")), jpgOptions, true);
        }
    }
}

// OS X file picker
function getPhotos(thePhoto) {
    if (thePhoto.name.match(/\.(png|jpg)$/i) != null || thePhoto.constructor.name == "Folder") {
        return true
    };
};

// JPG output options;
var jpgOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();  
jpgOptions.quality = 12; //enter number or create a variable to set quality  
jpgOptions.embedColorProfile = true;   
jpgOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;


// Replace SmartObject Contents
function replacePhoto(newFile, theSO) {
    app.activeDocument.activeLayer = theSO;
    // =======================================================
    var idplacedLayerReplaceContents = stringIDToTypeID("placedLayerReplaceContents");
    var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    desc3.putPath(idnull, new File(newFile));
    var idPgNm = charIDToTypeID("PgNm");
    desc3.putInteger(idPgNm, 1);
    executeAction(idplacedLayerReplaceContents, desc3, DialogModes.NO);
    return app.activeDocument.activeLayer
};


// Replace text strings
function replaceText(doc, layerName, newTextString) {
    for (var i = 0, max = doc.layers.length; i < max; i++) {
        var layerRef = doc.layers[i];
        if (layerRef.typename === "ArtLayer") {
        if (layerRef.name === layerName && layerRef.kind === LayerKind.TEXT) {
            layerRef.textItem.contents = decodeURI(newTextString);
        }
        } else {
            replaceText(layerRef, layerName, newTextString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hm. i'd probably consult the adobe support about this. sounds like a bug.

Comment: Could you please change the code provided so it'd only have a problem area? At the moment it's supposed to work with specific psd and includes a lot of code that has nothing to do with your question. Also, are you sure the font you're using supports umlauts?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy I have // alert(name); on line #30 that probably shows it the best. There isn't a problem area in the code as such, as Photoshop itself seems to be the problem.

So elements in this is 
1. A template with a SmartObject layer called Photo and a textlayer called Name
2. a photo with the persons name (the Photo variable), ie, Sergey Kritiskiy.jpg

Name string is handled fine until actually applied in the tempalte. I've checked fonts, and special characters are fine there.

Comment: @GottZ yeah, it's really weird. I asked over on their forums as well, but figured there may be experienced coders who've run into problems with Photoshop here as well :)

Comment: it works fine for me (http://prntscr.com/m5avev) so I guess this may be something specific to psd/font?

Comment: Or maybe the text encoding?

Comment: Photoshop doesn't like variables called "name". I think it's restricted. See for yourself `var name = "cheese"
alert(name); // "Adobe Photoshop"`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and tried everything I had in my developer toolbox... for around 3 hours ! without any success and then I found a little hack !
It seems that photoshop is uri encoding the name of the file but don't do it in a way that allow us to do a decodeURI() and get back those special characters.

For exemple instead of "%C3%A9" that should be "é" we get "e%CC%81". So what i do is a replace on the file name to the right UTF-8 code and then a decodeURI. Exemple :

```
var fileName = file.name
var result = fileName.replace(/e%CC%81/g, '%C3%A9') // allow é in file name
var myTextLayer.contents = decodeURI(result);
```

Then you can successfully get special chars and in my case accent from filename in your text layer.

You can do a replace for each characters you need for me it was :

```
'e%CC%81': '%C3%A9', //é
'o%CC%82': '%C3%B4', //ô
'e%CC%80': '%C3%A8', //è
'u%CC%80': '%C3%B9', //ù
'a%CC%80': '%C3%A0', //à
'e%CC%82': '%C3%AA' //ê
```

I took UTF-8 code from this HTML URL Encoding reference : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Hope it will help somebody one day because nothing existed online on this bug.